# Who lost to Glass Joe?

Tags: punch-out

In the game punch out, it is stated that Glass Joe's record is 1-99... Which means someone, somewhere, lost to Glass Joe.

Who is that guy that miraculously lost to Glass Joe? How did it happen? And what was Glass Joe's record entering that fight?

Comment: Joke answer: [Angry Video Game Nerd](https://youtu.be/MYDuy7wM8Gk?t=9m52s) while playing with a Power Glove

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> He has lost 99 times and has won once, in a freak accidental win against **Nick Bruiser,** states the Official Nintendo Magazine Punch-Out!! programmer.

[Source](http://punchout.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Joe)

Comment: Follow up on Nick Bruiser states that Nick was undefeated at 42-0, so that calls into question the programmer's statement. D: Conundrum!

Comment: Nick probably hit his head, had amnesia, then was considered a brand new fighter for the circuit and then went 42-0. That or nobody cared for continuity.

Comment: @Fredy31 / Fluttershy [*"...Nick Bruiser as the only boxer Joe had (allegedly) ever defeated."*](http://punchout.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Joe). The call was obviously contentious. Joe's team counts it as a win, Bruiser's doesn't honour the win. Sounds like we need a match up to "set the record straight!"

Comment: Would be fun to know how it happened. Was it a bad judge decision? (which would explain the 1 way recognition of the result)

Answer (score 3):

From [the Wiki](http://punchout.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Joe):

> He has lost 99 times and has won once, in a freak accidental win against Nick Bruiser, states the Official Nintendo Magazine Punch-Out!! programmer.

Looks like it's [Nick Bruiser](http://punchout.wikia.com/wiki/Nick_Bruiser) (by accidental victory).

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard that his win was against [Gabby Jay](http://punchout.wikia.com/wiki/Gabby_Jay), who himself got *his* one win against Glass Joe. Relatedly, I've also heard that one supposedly trained the other in the art of boxing, though it's often flip-flopped which.

I'm not sure. Official stance on Punch-Out canon has never been consistent, *especially* regarding Super Punch-Out!! (SNES).

As if having two titles shared between five games wasn't already confusing enough.